# Settings for a Service

Tags: android, settings

I have an Android App that is a service: it runs in the background invisibly to the user. This is accomplished as follows:

1. `MainActivity` starts up an `IntentService`, and then immediately finishes
2. All the work is done in the `IntentService`.
3. The style theme is fully translucent: `android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`.

This works beautifully!

However, I would like to offer the user the possibility to change some settings. This can not be achieved in the usual manner (`Preferences`) because we have no UI.

I am now considering creating a [Custom Account Type](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html) for the App. After all, in this manner change settings via the systems Settings App (icon: cog).

However, this is a bit of a hack.

1. `Custom Account`s are for Apps that require Authentication on a server. That does not apply.
2. Our Apps runs on an Android mini PC, and we ship hundreds of these devices with one single Google Account. Our users do not think of themselves as "users" or "account holders" like they would on their own phone.

I wonder:

- How other developers have managed changing setting for a service?
- Is `Custom Account Types` is considered a good idea?
- Or am I just opening a can of worms?

Comment: You can add a sticky notification which, upon interaction launches settings activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we ship hundreds of these devices with one single Google Account

I would expect that Google would be unhappy with your plan.

> How other developers have managed changing setting for a service?

Options include:

- Not having `MainActivity` `finish()` immediately, but instead offer settings right there, or via a separate activity accessible from there
- Having a separate launcher icon for your settings activity
- If your service is a foreground service, have an action on its `Notification` that leads to your settings activity
- If your `minSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, give your settings activity the following `<intent-filter>`, so the user can click over to your settings activity from a gear icon on your app's screen in the Settings app:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

> If Custom Account Types is considered a good idea?

Only if it is an actual account, one that the user would understand. So, in your case, based on your description, this is not a good idea IMHO.

Comment: A separate launcher icon for an activity. I never knew this was possible. That would be an elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: @IvoRenkema: You can have as many launcher activities as you want, just by having the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Ongoing (sticky) notification which launches settings activity upon interaction.

Comment: Interesting idea.